# How to format string with values from list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, format

How to print next values of list in place of `%s`? Code below shows result which I expect to get, but I don't want to write every step manually.

```
hours=["14","15","18","30"]
print (("%s:%s-%s:%s")%(hours[0],hours[1],hours[2],hours[3]))
```

Is there method to do something like this:

```
print (("%s:%s-%s:%s")%hours)
```

and make it work?

Comment: The real question: why are you using `%` formatting still?

Comment: I'm trying to learn Python. I have found % formatting examples in web tutorial. What's wrong with it? How should I write it in a proper way?

Comment: You should use `.format` which has superseded the `%` method. And on Python3.6, you can use f-strings instead of `format`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [format](https://pyformat.info), and use `*` to unpack values in the list as parameters to the `format` method:

```
"{}:{}-{}:{}".format(*hours)
# '14:15-18:30'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use unpacking directly in Python 3:

```
>>> ("%s:%s-%s:%s")%(*hours,)
'14:15-18:30'
```

Or convert to a tuple in Python 2:

```
>>> ("%s:%s-%s:%s")%tuple(hours)
'14:15-18:30'
```